# How do I change the value for a specific index in javascript es 6 or react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

I have an array like this

```
const data = [
 { id: 1, desc: 'desc 1' }, 
 { id: 2, desc: 'desc 2' }
]
```

and the select array like this

```
const listSelect = [
 { id: 10, title: ''title 1},
 { id: 20, title: 'title 2'}
]
```

I want to change the listSelect according to the index data, for example, How to do it?

Comment: How do the two relate to each other? None of the `id`s match, for instance, so...? Also note that you have a syntax error in the second one. Also, you've tagged React -- is this array in state? If so, it would be **much** better to show it in context.

Comment: You can make it much easier for people to help you by updating your question with a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: related to index, so I have array => "list schedule" in that array I have a select list, how do I know the select list in array => "list schedule"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to merge on the shared index, then a fairly simple function will do this in an immutable manner:

```js
const mergeByIndex = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .map ((x, i) => ({...x, ...ys[i]}))

const listSelect = [{id: 10, title: 'title 1'}, { id: 20, title: 'title 2'}]
const data = [{id: 1, desc: 'desc 1'}, {id: 2, desc: 'desc 2'}]

console .log (mergeByIndex (listSelect, data)) //=>
// [
//   {id: 1, title: "title 1", desc: "desc 1"},
//   {id: 2, title: "title 2", desc :"desc 2"}
// ]

console .log (mergeByIndex (data, listSelect)) //=>
// [
//   {id: 10, desc: "desc 1", title: "title 1"},
//   {id: 20, desc: "desc 2", title: "title 2"}
// ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We simply `map` over one list and do a shallow merge with the item and the item at the same index in the other list.

Note that the order you use to pass these will determine which version of common properties are selected.  A property from the second item will override the same-named property from the first.

If this is not what you meant, using the shared index, please explain more completely how you would choose matches.